# Jackson Circular Dependencies can't resolve or find correct solurion

Tags: hibernate, jackson, one-to-many, infinite-loop

I add annotation Jacson to my entity but problem with json infinity loop didn't resole.
What another solution is? Maybe add some different annotation.
With select from tables and transfer to List no problem, all work correct.

```java
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonManagedReference;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Question implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String question;


    @JsonManagedReference("question-answers")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
//  @Transient
    private List<Answer> answers;
// getters and setters
```

```java
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Answer implements Serializable{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String answer;

    private byte isCorrect;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
//  @JoinColumn(name="QuestionID")
    @JsonBackReference("question-answer")
    @JsonIgnore
//  @Transient
//  @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="QuestionID")
    private Question question;
```

Controller

```java
@RequestMapping("/home")
public @ResponseBody List<Question> home(){
    List<Question> qu = questionService.getQuestions();
    return qu;
```

I receive infinity loop of json on my page.
DAO

```java
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Question").list();
    }
```

So, again. What I must change in my cod fro normal work json?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used them before, but I guess that @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference need to have the same value so that Jackson link them together. In your example, both don't have the same value.

I am suggesting you try again by changing both annotations to have the same value, like below.

```
@JsonManagedReference("question-answers")

@JsonBackReference("question-answers")
```

Or don't specify any value. In this case the default value is "defaultReference". If you have more than one case in which you have to use this, then I guess you are forced to specify a value.

**[Update]**

I reproduced the infinite-loop case in my workspace. What I've observed is that the values in the annotations don't matter during serialization (java object -> json string) but they do matter in de-serialization (string -> json object).

When I attempted to reproduce the problem using different values in the @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference annotations, serialization worked fine, but the attempt to de-serialize ended up in an exception being thrown saying that a proper back reference with the specified value (annotation value) wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You may be reversed as follows:

In class Question:

From:

```
@JsonManagedReference("question-answers")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
private List<Answer> answers;
```

To:

```
@JsonBackReference("question-answers")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question")
private List<Answer> answers;
```

And in class Answer:

From:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonBackReference("question-answer")
@JoinColumn(name="QuestionID")
private Question question;
```

To:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonManagedReference("question-answer")
@JoinColumn(name="QuestionID")
private Question question;
```